# Retrieve GMail inbox with Indy 10

Tags: delphi, ssl, indy, pop3

I'm trying to build an application with Delphi, you have to read the Gmail inbox, and has to process emails for special purposes.

I built this application using Indy components POP3, part of the code is below.

```
procedure TfrmMain.LeerCorreos;
var
  mensaje: TIdMessage;
  i: Integer;
begin
  try
    with POP3 do
    begin
      Name := 'POP3';
      AutoLogin := False;
      Host := 'pop.gmail.com';
      Username := '*******@gmail.com';
      Password := '*****';
      Port := 995;
      IOHandler := IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
      UseTLS := utUseImplicitTLS;
    end;
    with IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL do
    begin
      Destination := 'pop.gmail.com:995';
      Host := 'pop.gmail.com';
      Port := 995;
      DefaultPort := 0;
    end;
    POP3.Connect;
    try
      Mensajes.Clear;
      mensaje := TIdMessage.Create(nil);
      try
        for i := 1 to POP3.CheckMessages do
        begin
          mensaje.Clear;
          POP3.RetrieveHeader(i, mensaje);
          Mensajes.Items.Add;
          Mensajes.Items[i - 1].SubItems.Add(mensaje.From.Address);
          Mensajes.Items[i - 1].SubItems.Add(mensaje.Subject);
          Mensajes.Items[i - 1].SubItems.Add(DateToStr(mensaje.Date));
        end;
      finally
        FreeAndNil(mensaje);
      end;
    finally
      POP3.Disconnect;
    end;
  except
    on e : Exception do
      ShowMessage('error=' + e.Message);
  end;
end;
```

Not work, responce "bad command'

Comment: Fantastic.... POP3.Login work.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

"Ok google!"

Tested with Indy 10.6.2.5298 and OpenSSL 1.0.2h, Delphi DX10 (not Update 1)

1) This line looks like not required. Why you going to set name to component which was created in design-time?

```
Name := 'POP3';
```

2) Try to make login after connect

```
POP3.Connect;
POP3.Login;
```

3) If you get error like `EIdReplyPOP3Error with message 'Web login required: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754`, perhaps you must use `application specific password` or turn on `Allow less secure apps` in Gmail settings

[image]

Comment: @MiguelMolina: `TIdPOP3.AutoLogin` is True by default.  When True, `TIdPOP3.Connect()` calls `TIdPOP3.Login()` automatically for you.  Since you are setting `TIdPOP3.AutoLogin` to False, you have to call `TIdPOP3.Login()` manually.